# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

When i print console.log(this.props.result.data) the console shows my object

[image]

But when i try to access this.props.result.data.attributes or anything inside the this.props.data i get a error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): this.props.result.data.attributes undefined is not an object.

Why this happened?

I see the attributes in the console

This object is returned by a fetch call for an api.

Here's my fetch code

```
export function* getPost() {
  console.log('Entrei no saga de pegar um post');
  const getPostsRequest = token => fetch(API_URL+'feed/posts/a6383507-1dd6-46b1-b27f-23f59ee3260b', {
                                      method: 'GET',
                                      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JWT }
                                    });

  const response = yield call(getPostsRequest);
  //console.log("fiz o fetch");
  //console.log(response);
  const result = yield response.json();

  yield put({ type: GET_POST_RESULT, result});
}
```

Comment: Post your fetch code.

Comment: I update the question with the fetch code ,i think its correct thats why i don't post before because my this.props.result.data is showing my object.

Comment: put the `getPostRequest` call and `response.json()` calls inside `try catch` blocks and see what the error is.

Comment: I put it in and it shows no error , I think this is working, if it were not my console.log(this.state.result.data) would be giving error too.